# Setting an SVG path in shadow DOM to visible:hidden

Tags: css, svg, shadow-dom

Is it possible to set an SVG path in the shadow DOM to visible:hidden or display: none?

Here's the SVG in the defs file:

```
<symbol id="plus-minus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <rect y="7" width="16" height="2" class="bar-horizontal"/>
    <rect x="7" width="2" height="16" class="bar-vertical"/>
</symbol>
```

Here's the SVG with the use tag:

```
<svg class="icon-plus-minus" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xlink:href="#plus-minus"></use>
</svg>
```

I'm trying to target the class "bar-horizontal" and hide it when an action is triggered.

Thanks!

Comment: why not sue Javascript `removeClass("bar-horizontal");`?

Comment: you can hide it but it will change for all instances of the symbol.

Comment: Robert, if I only hid it when it's parent had a class of X, or a certain attribute, it would only hide it on that instance, right? If so, how would I target it with pure CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the content of a **user-agent** Shadow DOM but only user created ones.

So you'll have to define 2 symbols, and apply the style `visibility:hidden` to the `<use>` element instead.

```
<svg>
    <symbol id="plus-minus-h" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <rect y="7" width="16" height="2"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="plus-minus-v" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <rect x="7" width="2" height="16" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
<svg class="icon-plus-minus" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xlink:href="#plus-minus-h" class="bar-horizontal"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#plus-minus-v" class="bar-vertical"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Supersharp.